# Maven - run play framework before starting tests

Tags: java, maven, playframework-2.4

some facts before asking the real question:

- My group and I are using Play!, Jenkins and Maven.
- We cannot change tools.
- We have one maven project and 2 different modules (client and server)

Now the question: We should do integration tests with the client. The only problem is that We can't manage to run the server before making client's test, and we do not want to deploy a dev-server just to make those tests.

Do you have any ideas on how to run Play! before Maven starts the client test?

Comment: so tests are located in the client module, the build of the client module should start the play server, run integration tests, tear down the play server, I suppose. When you say "we can't manage to run the server before making the client's test" what do you mean? what have you tried?

Comment: @A.DiMatteo Yes it's exactly what I mean.
We tried to execute 'sbt run' with an 'execution configuration' in the pom.xml, the command didn't find the server. 
But I don't know if this is the right way:  when I used the 'execution configuration' in another project in order to execute 'bower install' and 'npm install' the build waited until the end of the executions, while now we need to keep the server working for at least part of the tests.